# Is it always possible to construct a "product category" given any two arbitrary categories C and D?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I know that it may not always be possible to construct a "product object" for any two objects in a given category. That is not my question. My question is specifically about categories being "multiplied" to give a new category.

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: @DavidWheeler  The answer seems to be "yes" when I think about example categories. However... I guess I am wondering if it is always possible? For example, what would taking the product of some category C with **Cat** be; would that even be possible?

Comment: Why would it make a difference if you're taking the product with $\mathbf{Cat}$ rather than some other category?

Comment: The point is, create some candidate for such a categorical product, and show it satisfies the appropriate Universal diagram, and is, indeed a category.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Its a little bit clearer to me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product of two categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ has as its objects the pairs $(C,D)$ such that $C$ is an object of $\mathcal C$ and $D$ is an object of $\mathcal D$.  The morphisms from $(C,D)$ to $(C',D')$ in the product category are pairs $(f,g)$ such that $f:C\to C'$ in $\mathcal C$ and $g:D\to D'$ in $\mathcal D$.  Morphisms are composed componentwise.